# Django: python manage.py runserver (error)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I just started using Django for a web app project and I am going through the first tutorial but when I run the python manage.py runserver from the defualt mysite directory I get the following error.

I am using python 2.7 (64bit) on a windows 7 machine.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x00000000038AF828
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in
raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in pop
ulate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in impor
t_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 297,
in <module>
    class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 253, in __
new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, new_field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 307, in ad
d_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 672, in contribute_to_class
    cls._meta.add_field(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 312, in
 add_field
    self.local_fields.insert(bisect(self.local_fields, field), field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
```

here is the settings file:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '123'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: ...and your model.

Comment: @KlausD. what is the model ?  where do i find it?

Comment: You have not added any app yet, so you might have any model.

Comment: Did you migrate the database?

Comment: no i have not migrated it how is that done @KlausD.?

Comment: python manage.py migrate.. read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: C:\Users\HOJU\Desktop\django-tut\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__i
353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

Comment: @KlausD. i get the above error

Comment: @KlausD. do i need to install sqlite? from what i understand i comes standard with python 2.7 already?

Comment: No, it's part of the standard lib since 2.4 or 2.5.

Comment: I suppose your python version is latest 3.5. If possible use python 2.7 else try switching your db to postgres or mysql and try again.

Comment: @TarunBehal no im using 2.7